# Mongo Database Design

Tags: mongodb

I'm designing a website where people can book for events. The schema that I have designed, has some concurrency issues. Let me show the schema first:

```
{
  title: String,
  pricing: { [
    data: Date,
    package: String,
    price: Number
  ] },
  availability: { [
    date: Date,
    capacity: Number, // Number of users a vendor can take.
    booked: Number // Number of users booked the event for the date.
  ] }
}
```

Now an event's prices are unique by `Date` and `Package`. So a same date can have multiple prices if the package is different.

And the availability is unique by `Date` only. So I have to create a separate object for that.

**Problem**

The problem is, I have two different calls.

1. Save Availability (saves capacity for all dates at once. it's a **delete all and insert new** type call, but keep the value of `booked` the same)
2. Make a booking (increases `booked` by 1 for a particular date)

Since both resides in the same object, I think I will have a big concurrency issue in future because, if I save availability and at the same time users books the same event, the `booked` number might not be correct.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your post to update capacity from the client is something like

```
{
  id: ObjectId //Your event Id
  updates [
      {date: Date, capacity: newCapacity}, 
      {date: Date, capacity: newCapacity}
  ]   
}
```

You could keep the arrays how they currently are but you should be trying to target just the capacity property instead of overwriting the whole document. The query below will iterate through the post and update the `availablity` array targeting just the first item in the array that matches the query. I'm assuming javascript as the backend here but the idea is the same. If you have a lot of updates I would look into using `bulkUpdate` for performance

```
for(var i = 0; i < updates.length; i++) {
    var update = updates[i];
    db.collection.update(
        {
          _id: update.id, 
          "availability.date": update.date
        }, 
        {$set: {"availability.$.capacity": update.capacity}}
    )
}
```

for updating booked

```
for(var i = 0; i < updates.length; i++) {
        var update = updates[i];
        db.collection.update(
            {
              _id: update.id, 
              "availability.date": update.date
            }, 
            {"availability.$.booked": {$inc : 1}}
        )
    }
```

**EDIT** Example using bulk operation

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for(var i = 0; i < updates.length; i++) {
    var update = updates[i];
    bulk.find(
        {
          _id: update.id, 
          "availability.date": update.date
        }).update({$set: {"availability.$.capacity": update.capacity}})
    )
}
bulk.execute();
```

Comment: Yes, your assumption about my post to update is correct.
I thought of this too, but don't you think it would be a bad idea as well?
If I have 100 elements in the array, it will make 100 calls to the db?

Comment: As I currently have it written yes. But research bulk.find.update. I've used bulk operations for similar scenarios with thousands of records and it performs extremely well.

Comment: Thanks, will look into mongoose on how to do the same! :)

Comment: How do I `upsert` a subdocument in this case? If I update with a new date?

Comment: I would either send the original date in the post as well or add some kind of id field to your subdocuments.